# How to perform a self-update on a local web system?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, bitbucket, self-updating

I developed a web system (in CodeIgniter) for a client and it runs on a local machine inside his office. Whenever I need to update the system, I perform the following steps:

1. Access to server machine via TeamViewer;
2. I open [CMDER](http://cmder.net);
3. Access my account on Bitbucket to give a `git pull`;
4. I run the necessary migrations;

Thinking about these desktop systems that automatically look for a new version and upgrade, is it possible to do a routine in this web system to do the same thing? Search Bitbucket (or another web server) for a new version and then do the update?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Sure, you could set up a `cron` that does a regular `git pull` and runs migrations. Automated deployment is a common thing. There are many variants of the technique - cron's pretty nice and simple, but you can go pretty nutty with it if you really want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will search about cron and how to configure it in Windows using Xampp.

Comment: See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/managing-webhooks-in-bitbucket-server-938025878.html   ...   then all you need to do is set up a file that the webhook points to, and use exec to run git pull

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you using Web application like a Desktop? I mean instaled in the client instead in your server.

Comment: @wrivas At the time the client wanted a web system because it would host the system in the cloud. But time passed, and he did not choose to do that anymore.